# When run unit test, system kills my app in the middle of class's constructor before 3rd party library class call

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

In my Android project, I have a java class **MyWorker.java** :

```
public class MyWorker{
  private Context context;
  public MyWorker(Context context){
     this.context = context;
  }

  public void doWork(){
     Mission mission = new Mission(context);
     mission.do();
     ...
  }
}
```

The **Mission** class is as simple as (It uses a class from 3rd party library [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)):

```
public class Mission{
  private Context context;

  //ObjectMapper is a class from 3rd party library (Jackson JSON Processor)
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  public Mission(Context context){
    this.context = context;

    Log.i("tag", "The last log msg I see is this one!");
    //when test case runs unit test, system kills my app here…why?

    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Log.i("tag", "I don't see this log msg!");
  }
  ...
}
```

I would like to **unit test** the `doWork()` function of **MyWorker** class. Here is my test case:

```
public class MyWokerTest extends AndroidTestCase{
   private Context context;

   @Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception{
      super.setUp();
      context = getContext();   
   }

   @Override
   protected void runTest(){
     MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(context);
     worker.doWork();
   }
   ...

}
```

When I run above test case, I always see the following log from logcat:

```
I/tag(29538): The last log msg I see is this one!
I/ActivityManager(  551): Force stopping package com.my.app uid=10211
I/ActivityManager(  551): Killing proc 29538:com.my.app/u0a211: force stop
D/AndroidRuntime(29508): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(29508): GC_CONCURRENT freed 114K, 89% free 483K/4096K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
```

system kills my app before `mapper = newObjectMapper()` in the constructor of **Mission** class, why? Do I miss something when writing unit test for a class which uses 3rd party library???

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger? Are you sure it's not that the `ObjectMapper` constructor is throwing an exception? Are you sure you're running the latest code?

Comment: @Jon, I am very very sure. I have tried 10+ times stepping through, every time I checked every line of log from logcat. No exceptions, and every time after the last log msg before ObjectMapper, the system kills the process of my android app.

Comment: That's not what you said before - "it returns" is very different from "the system kills the process". Which is it?

Comment: Right, that's considerably clearer. Now, what happens if you call `new ObjectMapper()` directly in your test instead? Does *that* work? (And is there another log which might give you more detailed information about the reason for the force stop? Not being an Android dev, I'm not sure where I'd look...)

Comment: There is no problem to directly call new ObjectMapper() in my test case. I checked every line of logs which is already the most detailed info, didn't see anything else. I have showed my logs in my above post.

Comment: If you remove the call to the `ObjectMapper` constructor in your `Misson` constructor, does the constructor complete? (Just for the sake of diagnostics... I know it'll cause a problem elsewhere.) Can you step *into* the `ObjectMapper` constructor? Perhaps there's recursion causing a stack overflow which isn't being logged cleanly?